# Segment Control Scroll segment selected center only

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

Is there any way so that I can set segment control scroll and make selected at center only.

For example I have 1-2-3-4-5-6-7 segment controls. And Now now I have 4 in center then when I scroll 5 will come to the place of the 4 and 4 will shift to its left like that.

Comment: You can use `UIPageControl` to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Can't be done with Segment controls ?

Comment: You need to put your `UISegmentedControl` into a `scrollView` and then implement all the required `delegate` methods of `UIScrollView` to adjust your `segmentedControl`. Think, analyze and decide which one suits for your requirement.

Comment: Yes it can be done, it's exactly the same as if you used a UIPageControl.

Comment: @Santosh which methods of 'UISegmentedControl'?